# Does the break statement break out of multiple loops?

Tags: c, loops, break

If I have a while loop (a) inside another while loop (b) and I use the break statement while in the 'b' loop, does it also break out of the 'a' loop or do I stay in the 'a' loop?

Comment: That's something you could easily test out. But no, it doesn't break out of the outer loop

Comment: Have you bothered to look up *whatever* documentation you are working with? This is in *every* book, *every* tutorial, *every* reference.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where a `goto` is reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break;` only breaks from the innermost loop or `switch` body it appears in.

If you intend to break from nested loops, you might consider moving the nested loops to a separate function and using `return` to exit the function from any point inside its body.

Example:

```
    ...
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
    int value;
    ...
    int found = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] == value) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)
            break;
    }
    ...
```

Can be simplified as:

```
int hasvalue(int matrix[ROWS][COLS], int value) {
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] == value)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

    ...
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
    int value;
    ...
    found = hasvalue(matrix, value);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Does the break statement break out of multiple loops?**

[No](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.3p2):

> A break statement terminates execution of the smallest enclosing switch or iteration statement.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation on the `break` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break):

> Causes the enclosing for, while or do-while loop or switch statement to terminate.

The enclosing statement, singular.

Answer (score 1):

It breaks out of the inner most loop that contains it

https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-break-statement/

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      int x = foop();
      nargel();
      for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
         int k = fringle(i,j);
         if(are_we_done_yet(k))
            break; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<====== this goes
      }
      blink(); <<<<<<<<<<<<===== here
   }
```

some languages allow you to say which loop to break out of by giving the `for` a label, but not c. Java for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `break` works only on the current loop. You can't break the outmost loop from any enclosed loop with a single `break`, you'll need to set a flag in order to break at start of each loop when it becomes non-null.
It becomes way more tricky if you also use `continue` and multiple `break`/`continue` in the same loop level, but it can be done.

Example:

```
int must_break = 0 ;
...
...
for (int l1=0;l1<LIMIT1;l1++) {
  ...
  ...
  for (int l2=0;l2<LIMIT2;l2++ {
    ...
    ...
    for (int l3=0;l3<LIMIT3;l3++ {
      ...
      ...
      if (INTERNAL_BREAK_CONDITION) {
        // This flag will cause all outer loops to break instantly in cascade.
        must_break = 1 ;
        break ;   // Break L3
      }
    }
    // Must be placed just after the possibly breaking loop.
    if (must_break)   // Break L2
      break ;
  }
  // Must be placed just after the possibly breaking loop.
  if (must_break)   // Break L1
    break ;
}
// Here, you can test: if "must_break" is non-null, then a break occurred.
if (must_break)
  printf("Break detected!\n");
```

Or you can buy yourself a warm place in Hell and use a `goto` to break all loops... But obviously, it is very badly considered in most programming languages but Assembler. In C, outside low-level drivers / kernel modules, it's usually a "no-go" whatever happens. But it works... It's not maintainable, but it works.

Comment: In this code organisation, I think `goto` is more maintainable (and more readable) than the cascade of conditionals you propose. The `goto` is at least labelled.

Comment: @rici On such a short example, yes. On bigger code, it's not so obvious, _in particular if you partially break the loops_ (i.e. breaking L3 and L2, but not L1). Since it will jump to label position, **unconditionally**, a bit of code inserted where it should not be inserted and you're dead. That's why it's less maintainable to use a `goto`. But the real, good reason is that, during Middle Ages, we burnt people for less serious things than using a `goto` in C... :D It's better to always avoid this instruction, but if you're glued to CPU and do not have _ANY_ other choice.